# Pickle data truncated

Tags: python

While trying to send a list to a client process, I pickle it, but when I receive this on the client side it always gives me the error pickle data was truncated, and I don't know how to fix it.

sv

```
def handle_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('welcome to sv'))
    stock = random.sample(output, 1)
    order = pickle.dumps(stock)
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        if not data:
            break
    if data.decode('utf-8') == 'wanna trade!':
        print("trade order received")
        tcp.send(order)
    reply = connection.recv(2048)
    if reply.decode('utf-8') == 'Y':
       tcp.send(order)
       output.remove(order)
    elif reply.decode('utf-8') == 'N':
        print("doesn't wish to buy.")
    connection.close()
```

client

```
while True:
    Cliente.send(str.encode('wanna trade!'))
    recv = Cliente.recv(2048)
    if not recv:
        break
    if recv:
        Response = pickle.loads(recv)
        print(Response)
        Check = input('Y/N: ')
        Cliente.send(str.encode(Check))
    recv2 = Cliente.recv(2048)
    if recv2:
        final = pickle.load(recv2)
        purchases.append(final.decode('utf-8'))
        print(purchases)
Cliente.close()
```

Comment: How come one is using ´1024´ and the other is using ´2048´ in ´client.recv(#)’ ?

Comment: I tried messing around with the values to see if it did anything, already set both to 2048

Comment: And if you add a print of ´len()’ and ´data/recv[-50:]’ on each end, do they match?

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean, are you saying `print(len(data[-50]:))` server side and `print(len(recv[-50]:))` on client side?

Comment: pickle data may be longer then `2048` and you get from socket only `2048`  so you may get truncated data. You should create something better. You should first send pickle size - ie. integer converted to 4 bytes using module `struc` - and client should first get 4 bytes and use `struct` to convert it back to interger - and it should use this value in `recv(pickle_size)`

Comment: You should keep original code - and add new code at the end or create new question with new problem on new page. Now my answer doesn't fit to your question.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: You shows function `handle_client(connection)` but error suggets you have class `handler` with method `client` and it may need `client(self, connection)` to get positiona arguments - but if you use `client(connection)` then you may get your error because you forgot `self` - but you didn't show FULL error message so I can't confirm it.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to sleep after sending data - it is useless. Socket is low-level object and it sends all as-is and it doesn't care if you send all at once (with one `send()`) or in separated `send()` with delays - other side will see it always as one stream (without information where is end of data from first `send()`)

Comment: ah I didn't know! will remove it from my code then. also gonna roll back the edits, thanks for the help with this, it solved the issues I was having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't test it but data can be longer than 2048 bytes and when you get from socket only 2048 bytes then you get truncated data.

Socket doesn't know how many data to get in client so you have to send `size` before `data`. And `size` should have always the same length (so client will know if it get full size) so sending it as string may not work (or you would have to read size char after char until you get some spcial char - ie. new line which server would have to send after string with size.)

Server should first send data size (as ie. 4 bytes converted with `struct.pack()`) and later send data.

And client should first read 4 bytes and convert it to integer with `struct.unpack()` and later use this value to read all data.

Server:

```
import struct

stock = ...
data = pickle.dumps(stock)

size = len(data)
size_in_4_bytes = struct.pack('I', size)

print(size, size_in_4_bytes)

tcp.send(size_in_4_bytes)
tcp.send(data)
```

Client:

```
import struct

size_in_4_bytes = Cliente.recv(4)  # get only 4 bytes
size = struct.unpack('I', size_in_4_bytes)
size = size[0]

print(size, size_in_4_bytes)

data = Cliente.recv(size)
stock = pickle.loads(data)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you put code in functions then you could use it many times in simply way. You could use it also to send different object: pickle, normal string, data as JSON string, image, any file.

```
import struct

def send_data(conn, data):
    size = len(data)
    size_in_4_bytes = struct.pack('I', size)
    conn.send(size_in_4_bytes)
    conn.send(data)

def recv_data(conn):
    size_in_4_bytes = conn.recv(4)
    size = struct.unpack('I', size_in_4_bytes)
    size = size[0]
    data = conn.recv(size)
    return data

# -------------------------------------

# --- pickle ---

# send pickle
data = pickle.dumps(stock)
send_data(Client, data)

# recv pickle
data = recv_data(Client)
stock = pickle.loads(data)

# --- text ---

# send normal string
data = text.encode()
send_data(Client, data)

# recv normal string
data = recv_data(Client)
text = data.decode()

# --- JSON ---

# send data as JSON
stock = {'open': 12, 'close': 15}
text = json.dumps(stock)
data = text.encode()
send_data(Client, data)

# recv data as JSON
data = recv_data(Client)
text = data.decode()
stock = json.loads(text)
print(stock) # {'open': 12, 'close': 15}

# --- image (or any other file) ---

# send image
with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as image
    data = image.read()
    send_data(Client, data)

# recv image
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as image
    data = recv_data(Client)
    image.write(data)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working example.

Client first sends `text` and receives `text`, next it sends directory converted to JSON, and it receives JSON with other directory.

Server uses threads to run with many clients at the same time. There is `sleep()` to have time to start another client.

I use my code from answer for question:
[How to handle multithreading with sockets in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425239/how-to-handle-multithreading-with-sockets-in-python/68425926#68425926)

Server:

```
import socket
import threading
import time
import struct
import json

# --- functions ---

def send_data(conn, data):
    size = len(data)
    size_in_4_bytes = struct.pack('I', size)
    conn.send(size_in_4_bytes)
    conn.send(data)

def recv_data(conn):
    size_in_4_bytes = conn.recv(4)
    size = struct.unpack('I', size_in_4_bytes)
    size = size[0]
    data = conn.recv(size)
    return data

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print("[thread] starting")

    # ---
    
    # recv message
    
    data = recv_data(conn)
    text = data.decode()

    print("[thread] client:", addr, 'recv:', text)
    
    # simulate longer work - to start next client at the same time
    time.sleep(5) 

    # send message
    
    text = "Bye!"
    print("[thread] client:", addr, 'send:', text)

    data = text.encode()
    send_data(conn, data)
    
    # ---

    # recv JSON

    data = recv_data(conn)
    text = data.decode()
    stock = json.loads(text)

    print("[thread] client:", addr, 'recv:', stock)

    # send JSON

    stock = {'diff': stock['close'] - stock['open']}
    
    print("[thread] client:", addr, 'send:', stock)

    text = json.dumps(stock)
    data = text.encode()
    send_data(conn, data)
    
    # ---
    
    conn.close()

    print("[thread] ending")
   
# --- main ---


host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 8080

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # solution for "[Error 89] Address already in use". Use before bind()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

all_threads = []

try:
    while True:
        print("Waiting for client")
        conn, addr = s.accept()
    
        print("Client:", addr)
        
        t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        t.start()
    
        all_threads.append(t)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopped by Ctrl+C")
finally:
    if s:
        s.close()
    for t in all_threads:
        t.join()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import struct
import json

# --- functions ---

def send_data(conn, data):
    size = len(data)
    size_in_4_bytes = struct.pack('I', size)
    conn.send(size_in_4_bytes)
    conn.send(data)

def recv_data(conn):
    size_in_4_bytes = conn.recv(4)
    size = struct.unpack('I', size_in_4_bytes)
    size = size[0]
    data = conn.recv(size)
    return data

# --- main ---

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 8080

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

print("Connected to the server")

# ---

# send message

text = "Hello"

print('send:', text)

data = text.encode()
send_data(s, data)

# recv message

data = recv_data(s)
text = data.decode()

print('recv:', text)

# ---

# send JSON

stock = {'open': 12, 'close': 15}

print('send:', stock)

text = json.dumps(stock)
data = text.encode()
send_data(s, data)

# recv JSON

data = recv_data(s)
text = data.decode()
stock = json.loads(text)

print('recv:', stock)

# ---

s.close()
```

Similar way client could send filename and server could send back image data. But for files it may need receiving in chunks because socket has limited buffer. It may need also to send extra iformation if server found image or not.

Comment: It gave me an error in my function, maybe because I call it elsewhere not sure but I tried implementing it in my socket nonetheless, and I've reached a point where it has no errors but there isn't communication. I edited my initial post, to show how I tried to implement this and to show where the handle_client function was being called.

Comment: Nevermind I managed to fix this, only have 1 minor issue left to fix. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could put my code in functions to simply use it many times. I put example code which shows that you could use it to send not only `pickle` but also normal string, JSON, or image file (or any other file).

Comment: I added minimal working code for `Server` and `Client` so everyone can simply copy it and test it.