# getting speed issues with tcp communication and getting data truncated problem with udp communication

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

I need to send huge number of logs in json format to a program that examine them for issues. Tried using udp first. Data are sent and received instantly but losing 30% of them. (I discard any incomplete json)

Then I try an answer from stackoverflow
[How to handle multithreading with sockets in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425239/how-to-handle-multithreading-with-sockets-in-python/68425926#68425926)

```
import threading
import time


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print("[thread] starting")

    # recv message
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print("[thread] client:", addr, 'recv:', message)
    
    # simulate longer work
    time.sleep(5)

    # send answer
    message = "Bye!"
    message = message.encode()
    conn.send(message)
    print("[thread] client:", addr, 'send:', message)
    
    conn.close()

    print("[thread] ending")
   
host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 8080

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # solution for "[Error 89] Address already in use". Use before bind()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

all_threads = []

try:
    while True:
        print("Waiting for client")
        conn, addr = s.accept()
    
        print("Client:", addr)
        
        t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        t.start()
    
        all_threads.append(t)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopped by Ctrl+C")
finally:
    if s:
        s.close()
    for t in all_threads:
        t.join()
```

This solves the data lose problem but it is very slow. I suspect the sending can be a problem coz I need to keep opening and closing the socket in order to send all rows in the csv.

```
def send_data(conn, data):
    size = len(data)
    size_in_4_bytes = struct.pack('I', size)
    conn.send(size_in_4_bytes)
    conn.send(data)

def recv_data(conn):
    size_in_4_bytes = conn.recv(4)
    size = struct.unpack('I', size_in_4_bytes)
    size = size[0]
    data = conn.recv(size)
    return data

def logLoop(ip, port, logPath):
#    sock = socket.socket()
    with open(logPath, newline='') as csvFile:
        cReader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in csvFile), delimiter=',')
        next(cReader)
        for r in cReader:
            sent = 0
            while not sent:
                try:
                    sock = socket.socket()
#                    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                    sock.connect((ip, port))
                    text = json.dumps(r)
                    data = text.encode()
                    send_data(sock, data)
                    sock.close()
                    sent = 1
                except (ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionResetError, BrokenPipeError) as error:
                    print ("failed")
                    pass

    return
```

I read some tutorials on socket communication and that is all I know. Any advice on sending all logs without losing data and in reasonable speed?

Comment: Don't open/close the socket for each line sent.  That's expensive and slow.  No need to send the CSV as JSON.  Send the size and then the whole CSV file.  Use `sendall()`.  Buffer received data until you receive the whole size sent.  `recv(n)` only receives a *maximum* of n bytes so check the return value.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I dont understand what you mean by recv(n) only receives a maximum of n bytes so check the return value. Can you illustrate with a line of code?

Comment: `message = sock.recv(size)` can receive 1-size bytes (or 0 if the socket is closed).  Don't assume you will get "size" bytes.  Check the return value.  If len(message) < size, then `recv(size - len(message))` until you have the whole message.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean throw away the threading and create a loop to do what you suggest? Or write a different handle client function and get threading to work with what you suggest.

Comment: Threading is fine to handle multiple clients in parallel.  I'm just saying use the socket functions correctly.  TCP is not message-based. It is a byte stream only, and you get whatever is ready to be received.