# not responding in tkinter when click button completely

Tags: python, tkinter

Client Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import tkinter.messagebox
from PIL import Image
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def ConnectToServer():
    HOST=entry.get()
    PORT=65432
    test=True
    try:
        s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    except Exception as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title="Error",message="Error")
        test=False
    if test:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Noti",message="Connect Successfully")
def takeScreen():
    msg="TAKEPIC"
    s.sendall(bytes(msg,"utf8"))
    file = open('server_image.jpg', "wb")
    image_chunk = s.recv(2048)
    while image_chunk:
        if not image_chunk:
            break
        file.write(image_chunk)
        image_chunk = s.recv(2048)
    file.close()
return



def Thoat():
    msg="QUIT"
    s.sendall(bytes(msg,"utf8"))
    s.close()
    root.destroy()


def thread1():
    t1=threading.Thread(target=takeScreen)
    t1.start()

def thread2():
    t2=threading.Thread(target=ProcessRunning)
    t2.start()  


root = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()
entry=tk.Entry()
myButton_connect=tk.Button(text="Connect",command=ConnectToServer)
myButton_TakePic = tk.Button(text="Take screenshot", command=thread1, font=10)
myButton_Process = tk.Button(text="Process Running", command=thread2, font=10)
myButton_Exit=tk.Button(text="Thoat",command=Thoat,font=10)
canvas1.create_window(150,50,window=entry)
canvas1.create_window(150, 100, window=myButton_TakePic) 
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=myButton_Process)
canvas1.create_window(250,50,window=myButton_connect)
canvas1.create_window(150,200,window=myButton_Exit)
root.mainloop()
```

Server code:

```
def pic():

    myScreenshot=pyautogui.screenshot()

    save_path=asksaveasfilename()

    myScreenshot.save(save_path+"_capture1.png")

    return save_path+"_capture1.png"

HOST=''
PORT=65432
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen()
while True:
    conn,addr=s.accept()
    while True:
        data=conn.recv(1024).decode("utf8")
        if data=="TAKEPIC":
            path=pic()
            im=Image.open(path)
            im.show()
            file=open(path,'rb')
            img_data=file.read(2048)
            while img_data:
                conn.send(img_data)
                img_data=file.read(2048)
            file.close()   
        elif data=="app running":
            Process(conn)   
        elif data=="QUIT":
            break;
    break;

s.close()
```

img_gui_tkinter:

[image]

After I clicked the "Take screenshot" button, the server program still took pictures and saved them, then it sent to the client successfully (because I was able to open the image).

But the problem is that it pops up a dialog like this:

img_after click take screenshot:

[image]

and make my program hang. When I press the close button on the child dialog box, it appears

img_hanging error:

[image]

If you choose Close the program, the program on the server side will end.

I found that the client side has an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KHAI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\MangMaYTinh\TuHoc_DoAn\CreateBox_control\Box_Control.py", line 29, in takeScreen
    image_chunk = s.recv(2048)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host


Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KHAI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\KHAI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "d:\MangMaYTinh\TuHoc_DoAn\CreateBox_control\Box_Control_Ver3.py", line 31, in takeScreen
    image_chunk = s.recv(2048)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I've tried to the best of my ability but still can't resolve that error. Hope everyone can help me. I'm just getting started with Python

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: when you click button then it runs server with `while`-loop which may block `root.mainloop()` which has to run all time to get key/mouse events from system (Windows, Mac, Linux) and send them to widgets, and update/redraw window. If `mainloop` is blocked then window freezes. You will have the same problem in any other GUI framework (PyQt, wxPython, PyGTK, Kivy) or game/media framework (PyGame, Pyglet). `while`-loop (or all `socket`) may have to run in separated thread.

Comment: @furas I edited the code with thread as you say but my problem is hapenning

Comment: I don't see any threads in your code. See my answers for other questions with code which runs `socket` in separated `thread` - [How to handle multithreading with sockets in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425239/how-to-handle-multithreading-with-sockets-in-python/68425926#68425926) or [Pickle data truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425224/pickle-data-truncated)

Comment: at this moment I try to convert  your code to `minimal working code` (because you didn't do this) to run it and make modifications.

Comment: BTW: see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - ie. `lower_case_names` for functions; spaces aroung `=` when you assign to variable; space after `,` - all this makes code more readable.

Comment: @furas, thanks for your helping. I fixed hanging error but child windown still appears when i take screen. I don't click "close" on this, so my programming OK but when i click it, my client exit with Traceback i mentioned.

Comment: @furas one more bug i have just detected. If i don't click "close" on child windown, my programming OK. But when i click "QUIT"="Thoat" in my language, program appears Traceback: `Exception in thread Thread-1:`

Comment: alway show full error message in question (not in comment).

Comment: you have `command=Exit` but you don't have `def Exit():...` - and this can raise error. Maybe you means `command=exit` with lower `e`. BUT If you want to close window then you should rather use `command=root.destroy`

Comment: `Exception in thread Thread-1:` may means you have to stop thread before exiting. You can use `while running:` instead of `while True:` - and when you set `running = False` then it should stop loop and finish thread.

Comment: maybe you see second window - because server runs `asksaveasfilename()` and it opens main window. I don't use it so I don't see second window - because normally client can't access window opened on server so `asksaveasfilename()` will be useless. OR on server you should first create `root = tk.Tk()` and hide it `root.widraw()` before you use `asksaveasfilename()`

Comment: Thanks you very much, I have really no words to express my gratitude. You are the first people in this community to help me so wholeheartedly. Thanks you very much

Comment: @furas love you man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems.

Main problem is that `socket` is low-level object and it doesn't know if it received all file data so it runs next `recv(2048)` which waits for more data - and this blocks socket and all code.

Code `if not image_chunk: break` works only when you close socket after sending data but you need socket to send other commands so you can't close it after sending file. You have to send file size before data and then client will know how many data to receive.

you can use `struct` to convert integer to 4 bytes - so client will have to receive 4 bytes to get size (and convert to integer using `struct`). Using string with number you don't know how long will be this string and client will not know how many bytes to receive.

---

Other problem is that sending file may need longer time and socket blocks `mainloop` which get key/mouse events from system, send events to widgets, update/redraw window/widgets - so GUI freezes.

I skiped this problem. It would need longer and more complex code with `thread`.

---

My version with other changes.

**server.py**

```
import socket
#from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
#from PIL import Image
import pyautogui
#import threading
import struct
import os

import datetime

# --- functions ---

def take_screenshot():   # PEP8: verb as function name

    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
                                         # PEP8: spaces around `=`

    # using `asksaveasfilename()` (or any other GUI elements) on server is useless - user can't see GUI from server
    #path = asksaveasfilename()
    #path = path + "_capture1.png"
    path = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f_capture.png')
    screenshot.save(path)

    return path

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    while True:
        print('[handle_client] read command')
        command = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf8")
        command = command.lower()

        print('[handle_client] run command:', command)
        
        if command == "takepic":
            print('[handle_client] take screenshot')
            path = take_screenshot()

            # displaying on serer make no sense because user can't see it.
            #im = Image.open(path)
            #im.show()
            
            file_size = os.stat(path).st_size
            print('[handle_client] file size:', file_size)
            file_size = struct.pack('>I', file_size)  # convert `integer` to `4 bytes`
            conn.send(file_size) 

            print('[handle_client] open file')
            file_handler = open(path,'rb')

            total_size = 0
            while True:
                print('[handle_client] read data chunk from file')
                data_chunk = file_handler.read(2048)

                size = len(data_chunk)
                if not data_chunk:
                    break

                total_size += size
                print('[handle_client] send data chunk:', size, 'total:', total_size)
                conn.send(data_chunk)

            print('[handle_client] close file')
            file_handler.close()
            
        elif command == "app running":
            Process(conn)
        elif command == "quit":
            conn.close()
            break

# --- main ---

HOST = ''  # PEP8: spaces around `=`
PORT = 65432  # PEP8: spaces around `=`

print('Starting ...')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # PEP8: space after `,`
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # solution for "[Error 89] Address already in use". Use before bind()
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()


#all_threads = []
all_clients = []

try:
    while True:
        print('Waiting for client')
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        print('Handle client')

        # run in current thread - only one client can connect
        handle_client(conn, addr)
        all_clients.append( (conn, addr) )
        
        # run in separated thread - many clients can connect
        #t = threading.Thread(taget=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        #t.start()
        #all_threads.append(t)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopped by Ctrl+C')
finally:
    s.close()
    #for t in all_threads:
    #    t.join()
    for conn, addr in all_clients:
        conn.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from PIL import Image
import threading
import struct

# --- functions ---

def connect_to_server():   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    HOST = entry.get()   # PEP8: spaces around `=`
    PORT = 65432

    try:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))  # PEP8: `
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Noti", message="Connect Successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message="Error: " + str(e))

def take_screen():
    msg = "TAKEPIC"

    print('[take_screen] send command:', msg)
    s.sendall(msg.encode())

    file_size = s.recv(4)
    file_size = struct.unpack('>I', file_size)[0]  # convert `4 bytes` to `integer`
    print('[take_screen] file size:', file_size)
    
    print('[take_screen] open file')
    file_handler = open('server_image.jpg', "wb")

    total_size = 0
    while total_size < file_size:
        print('[take_screen] recv data chunk')
        data_chunk = s.recv(2048)

        size = len(data_chunk)
            
        total_size += size
        print('[handle_client] write data chunk:', size, 'total:', total_size)
        file_handler.write(data_chunk)

    print('[take_screen] close file')
    file_handler.close()

    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Success", message="Downloaded Successfully")

def on_exit():
    msg = "QUIT"

    print('[on_exit] send command:', msg)
    s.sendall(msg.encode())
    
    s.close()
    root.destroy()
        
# --- main ---

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

entry = tk.Entry()

button_connect = tk.Button(text="Connect", command=connect_to_server)
button_take_pic = tk.Button(text="Take screenshot", command=take_screen)
#button_process = tk.Button(text="Process Running", command=processrunning)
button_exit = tk.Button(text="Exit", command=on_exit)

canvas.create_window(150, 50,  window=entry)
canvas.create_window(150, 100, window=button_take_pic)
#canvas.create_window(150, 150, window=button_process)
canvas.create_window(250, 50 , window=button_connect)
canvas.create_window(150, 200, window=button_exit)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Pyhon Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)