# receiving back data from the client

Tags: python, numpy, sockets, client-server

I sent a scaled array using socket connection from the server to the client and it worked well now I wanted to send back the data to the server to unscale it in the server. The data is sent to the client each row at a time so I try to put them back in order in an empty array called final.

This is the server.py

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

i = 0
scaler_ti = MinMaxScaler()
test_inputs = []
test_inputs = np.array(test_inputs)
temp_in = pd.read_excel(r'K:\BachelorThesis\Data\TestingData\Mix_Data_inputs.xlsx')
test_inputs = temp_in.to_numpy()
rows = test_inputs.shape[0]
scaler_ti.fit(test_inputs)
normalized_test_inputs = scaler_ti.transform(test_inputs)


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
port = 62402
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)

while True:

    connection, clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"connection from {address} has been established!")
    strg = test_inputs
    temp = strg.tobytes()
    clientsocket.send(temp)
    clientsocket.close()

    if i in range(65533):
        i = i + 1
        msg = connection.recv(64)
        out = np.frombuffer(msg)
        inverse = scaler_ti.inverse_transform(out.reshape(1,8))
        print(inverse)
```

This is the client.py

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
from random import randint

i = 0
final = []
final = np.array(final)
#modelLSTM = load_model('K:\BachelorThesis\code testing\TireForces.LSTM/LSTM_model.h5')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 62402
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    if i in range(65533):
        i = i + 1
        msg = s.recv(64)
        out = np.frombuffer(msg)
        #out = out.reshape(1,8)
        #out = out.reshape(1,1,8)
        #prediction = modelLSTM.predict(out)
        #inverse = scaler_ti.inverse_transform(prediction.reshape(1,8))
        #print(prediction)
        #print(inverse)
        final = np.vstack(out) 
        print(out)
        if len(msg) <= 0:
             break
    strg = final
    temp = strg.tobytes()
    s.send(temp)
    #serversocket.close()
#print (final)
```

This is the error I get from the server.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\BachelorThesis\code testing\server.py", line 26, in <module>
    connection, clientsocket, address = s.accept()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

This is the error I get from the client.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\BachelorThesis\code testing\client.py", line 31, in <module>
    final = np.vstack(out)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in vstack
  File "C:\Users\karim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 283, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

Comment: `accept` always gives only two values `connection, address` but you expect three values `connection, clientsocket, address` and this is your problem. As for me `connection` and `clientsocket` means exactly the same. And you should use only one of this names in all code - but don't close it - `clientsocket.close()` - before you send all data.

Comment: see documentation for [accept](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) - there is `"The return value is a pair (conn, address) ..."`

Comment: if you had all time `connection, clientsocket, address` then your code couldn't run and it couldn't send anything. Maybe you was running different code - with `(conn, address) = s.accept()`

Comment: BTW: `socket` is `low-level networking interface` and it doesn't know how much data you send and how much data it has to reveived so using `if len(msg) <= 0: break` may work only if you close connection but later you want use this connection to get send data and it will not work. You have to build something more complex - first send data size and later send data. And other side should first get data size and later read data until you get all data. There was few question in last weeks in which I saw how to do this.

Comment: Frankly, your code looks like you join two different codes. But it will not work because `socket` is `low-level networking interface` and you have to do it in different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that `accept()` always sends only two values but you expect three.

It should be

```
 connection, address = s.accept()
```

and you should use `connection` instead of `clientsocket`

---

But it will give other problem because you close `clientsocket` after sending data but you need this connection also to receive data.

All this looks like you joined two codes. These codes could work separatelly but it will not work together - because both needs to close connection to inform that this is end of data but now you can't close it after sending because you need connection to receive other data.

You have to use different way to inform other side that it is end of data. You have to first send data size (as object with constant size so sending as string will not work because it may have different length for different numbers) and later send data. And then other side has to first get data size (as object with constant size) and later use thsi value to detect if it get all data.

You can use `struct` to convert `integer` size to 4 bytes (so it will have constant size for different values) and other side will have to read 4 bytes and use again `struct` to convert back to `integer`

I can't run it but here is code.

Server:

```
import socket
import struct

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# --- functions ---

def send_data(connection, data):
    data_size = len(data)
    data_size_as_4_bytes = struct.pack('>I', data_size)
    
    connection.send(data_size_as_4_bytes)    
    connection.send(data)

def recv_data(connection, chunk_size=64):
    data_size_as_4_bytes = connection.recv(4)
    data_size = struct.unpack('>I', data_size_as_4_bytes)[0]
    
    data = b""
    size = 0

    while size < data_size:
        chunk = connection.recv(chunk_size)
        size += len(chunk)
        data += chunk
    
    return data

# --- main ---

scaler_ti = MinMaxScaler()

temp_in = pd.read_excel(r'K:\BachelorThesis\Data\TestingData\Mix_Data_inputs.xlsx')

test_inputs = temp_in.to_numpy()
rows = test_inputs.shape[0]

scaler_ti.fit(test_inputs)
normalized_test_inputs = scaler_ti.transform(test_inputs)

# -- send ---

HOST = ''  # or '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 62402

#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = socket.socket()  # default values are `socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM`
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # solution for '[Error 89] Address already in use'. Use before bind()
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

try:
    while True:
        print('Waiting for client')

        # wait for new client
        connection, address = s.accept()
        print(f"connection from {address} has been established!")
        
        # --- send data ---
        
        print('send:', test_inputs)
        
        data = test_inputs.tobytes()
        send_data(connection, data)
        
        # don't close it because it is needed to receive data
        #clientsocket.close()

        # --- receive data ---

        data = recv_data(connection)
        output_data = np.frombuffer(data)
        
        print('recv:', output_data)

        # --- now you can close ---

        connection.close()
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopped by Ctrl+C")
finally:
    s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import struct

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
from random import randint

# --- functions ---

def send_data(connection, data):
    data_size = len(data)
    data_size_as_4_bytes = struct.pack('>I', data_size)
    
    connection.send(data_size_as_4_bytes)    
    connection.send(data)

def recv_data(connection, chunk_size=64):
    data_size_as_4_bytes = connection.recv(4)
    data_size = struct.unpack('>I', data_size_as_4_bytes)[0]
    
    data = b""
    size = 0

    while size < data_size:
        chunk = connection.recv(chunk_size)
        size += len(chunk)
        data += chunk
    
    return data

def some_calcuations(input_data)

    # need something different
    output_data = input_data
    
    return output_data

# --- main ---

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 62402
s.connect((host, port))

# --- recv ---

data = recv_data(s)
input_data = np.frombuffer(msg)

print('recv:', input_data)

# --- calculations ---

output_data = some_calcuations(input_data)

# --- send ---

print('send:', output_data)

data = output_data.tobytes()
send_data(s, data)

# --- close ---

s.close()
```

---

**BTW:**

Last week there was similar question where I show working code - and it also use `threading` to run server for many clients at the same time.

Use socket to send image (screenshot) when GUI is runnig:
[not responding in tkinter when click button completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430982/not-responding-in-tkinter-when-click-button-completely)

Use socket to send pickle:
[Pickle data truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425224/pickle-data-truncated)

Use socket in threading in server to work with many clients:
[How to handle multithreading with sockets in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425239/how-to-handle-multithreading-with-sockets-in-python)

---

**EDIT:**

Version which send in loop.

After all rows it sends word `end` to inform that it is end of data.

Or it could send number of rows before data.

**Server:**

```
import socket
import numpy as np

import struct

# --- functions ---

def send_data(connection, data):
    data_size = len(data)
    data_size_as_4_bytes = struct.pack('>I', data_size)
    
    connection.send(data_size_as_4_bytes)    
    connection.send(data)

def recv_data(connection, chunk_size=64):
    data_size_as_4_bytes = connection.recv(4)
    data_size = struct.unpack('>I', data_size_as_4_bytes)[0]
    
    data = b""
    size = 0

    while size < data_size:
        chunk = connection.recv(chunk_size)
        size += len(chunk)
        data += chunk
    
    return data

# --- main ---

np.random.seed(0)  # it will always gives the same random numbers
test_inputs = np.random.random_sample((3,5))

# -- send ---

HOST = ''  # or '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 62402

#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = socket.socket()  # default values are `socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM`
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  # solution for '[Error 89] Address already in use'. Use before bind()
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

try:
    while True:
        # --- wait for new client ---

        print('Waiting for client')
        
        connection, address = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")

        # --- send ---
        
        for row in test_inputs:
        
            # --- send data ---
            
            print('send:', row)
            
            data = row.tobytes()
            send_data(connection, data)

            # --- receive data ---

            data = recv_data(connection)
            row = np.frombuffer(data)
            
            print('recv:', row)

        # information that it is end of data 
        send_data(connection, 'end'.encode())

        # --- now you can close ---
        
        connection.close()
        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopped by Ctrl+C")
finally:
    s.close()
```

**Client:**

```
# author: Bartlomiej "furas" Burek (https://blog.furas.pl)
# date: 2021.07.23
#
# title: receiving back data from the client
# url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499599/receiving-back-data-from-the-client/68502806#68502806

import socket
import numpy as np
from random import randint

import struct

# --- functions ---

def send_data(connection, data):
    data_size = len(data)
    data_size_as_4_bytes = struct.pack('>I', data_size)
    
    connection.send(data_size_as_4_bytes)    
    connection.send(data)

def recv_data(connection, chunk_size=64):
    data_size_as_4_bytes = connection.recv(4)
    data_size = struct.unpack('>I', data_size_as_4_bytes)[0]
    
    data = b""
    size = 0

    while size < data_size:
        chunk = connection.recv(chunk_size)
        size += len(chunk)
        data += chunk
    
    return data

def some_calcuations(input_data):

    # need something different
    output_data = input_data
    
    return output_data

# --- main ---

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 62402
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    # --- recv ---

    data = recv_data(s)

    if data == b'end':
        break

    input_data = np.frombuffer(data)

    print('recv:', input_data)

    # --- calculations ---

    output_data = some_calcuations(input_data)

    # --- send ---

    print('send:', output_data)
    
    data = output_data.tobytes()
    send_data(s, data)

# --- close ---

s.close()
```

Comment: your code works perfectly for sending and receiving data, but it created a problem which is I want to send each row separately after running the code once, and your code just sends the first row then receives it and stops. I don't want it to seem like I don't appreciate what you've done, because I do appreciate what you have done. I will try and show what I mean in the following comments.

Comment: This is what was printed on client.py                                                 
K:\BachelorThesis\code testing>py client.py
recv: [1.64230914e-06 1.64223900e-06 3.75934565e-06 ... 4.32141162e-02
 1.33275070e+01 5.08212345e-03]
send: [1.64230914e-06 1.64223900e-06 3.75934565e-06 ... 4.32141162e-02
 1.33275070e+01 5.08212345e-03]

K:\BachelorThesis\code testing>

Comment: I couldn't explain what else I needed so I posted it as an answer can you please look at it thanks in advance. furas

Comment: I created code to send all as one item - if you want to send every row separatelly then you have to every row convert to bytes separatelly and send it with own `size` - and you would have to run it in loop. And it would need to send information how many rows you will send so other side will know how many rows to receive. So it will need more code. I will create it later.

Comment: I added version which sends in loop

Comment: really thank you man I do appreciate what you have done

Comment: furas can you please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518216/when-converting-to-tobytes-it-changes-the-numpy-array-valueerror-expected-2d